# Can't rewrite Mage Review Grid

Tags: overrides, review, grid

Trying to rewrite the "Product Review" (tab) grid inside customer edit page, below my code

my xml:

```
 <blocks>
          <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                      <review_grid>Myc_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Grid</review_grid>              
                </rewrite>
           </adminhtml>
 </blocks>
```

my extended class:

```
   class Myc_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Grid
    {

    public function __construct()
    {
        die('test');
        $this->setId('reviewcustomgrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
       die('test');
       ......rest of collection code...

    }
```

is not rewriting the grid, i tried to put a die its always loading the Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Grid.

is not the fist time i am doing rewrites, but this time i cant find the solution, there is something i am missing?

Thanks

UPDATE-
Adminhtml is the module, i use this module to place all general rewrites. i have other blockS and modelS rewrites here

Comment: <blocks> in tag <global> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Grid` is the base class for two other block classes:

1. `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Reviews` - review grid in product tab
2. `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_Reviews` - review grid in customer tab

So if you want to have your rewrite applied in all places, you need to rewrite these two classes as well.

Comment: It works! i thought i just had to edit the base class to edit the grid, really Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think issue in

```
  <review_grid>Myc_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Grid</review_grid>
```

After `Myc` `modulename` is missing

```
Myc_YOUR_MODULENAME_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Grid
```

Comment: Adminhtml is the module, i use this module to place all general rewrites. i have other block and model rewrites here

Comment: in which place your are writing die? Can you show your whole file ? @RiccardoRichGiacomelli

Comment: see above, edited/updated my question